# Is it correct to say "I couldn't help but ate the cake" and "I couldn't help but eat the cake"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

I thought it was bad to eat the cake but I still ate a cake yesterday.

Which of the followings are correct?

1- "*I couldn't help but ate the cake*"

2- "*I couldn't help but eat the cake*"

3- "*I shouldn't have eaten that cake but I couldn't help myself and ate it*"

4- "*I couldn't help eating that cake*"

Comment: 2,3,4 are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"cannot help but"/"can't help but"/"could not help but"/"couldn't help but" are examples of an idiom that is followed by an infinitive. In this case the infinitive is "eat": "I couldn't help but eat the cake". You can't use the past tense or other verb forms after "help but" in this idiom.

The [Grammarphobia blog](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/08/cant-help-but.html) has written about this. Some usage guides say not to use "help but" in formal writing, but most people think it's fine. Examples they give include:

- I couldn’t help but cry over that.
- They cannot help but feel the responsibilities.
- Sympathy is an impulse which we cannot help but experience for one another.

There are many other ways of using "help": "I couldn't help myself" on its own is another [idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cannot%20help%20oneself), meaning "I was unable to control myself". You can also use "I couldn't help eating", which means the same as "I couldn't help but eat" - which is confusing. So 2, 3, 4 are correct, but not 1.